# Series expansion of $xy'=y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm asked to

> find a power series of the form $\sum a_n x^n$, recognize the resulting series as the expansion of a familiar function, then verify my conclusion by solving the equation directly.

Given $xy'=y$.  However, I'm getting $a_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n! x^n)^{-1}$, which doesn't appear to match any functions that I know right now at least.  (I was also expecting something involving $e$ just from looking at it.)

Here's what I got so far:

$$let \ \ y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
$$y'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$$
$$xy'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^n$$
and since $xy'=y$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1} x^{n-1}$$
$$na_nx^n=a_{n-1} x^{n-1}$$
$$a_nnx=a_{n-1}$$
$$a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}{nx}$$

taking $a_0=a_0$

$$a_1=\frac{a_0}{x}, \qquad a_2=\frac{a_0}{2x^2} \qquad a_3=\frac{a_0}{6x^3}$$

and generally,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_0}{n!x^n}$$

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is correct 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^n=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$$

$$-a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n(n-1)=0$$
$$\implies a_0=0$$
And
$$\implies a_n(n-1)x^n=0 \implies n=1  \implies a_1 \ne 0 $$
$$ \implies n \ne 1 \implies a_n=0$$
The coefficent are zero except for $n=1$

Finally
$$y=a_1x$$

---

Note that
$$a_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n! x^n)^{-1}=a_0e^{1/x}$$
Since we have that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n!}=e^x$$

Comment: Oh, I see!  I missed that $a_0$.  Wow, thanks!

Comment: yes you're welcome @Cullub